# Add editable field to list

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am trying to add an editable field to a list, however when I add the `<text ... >` item below it makes the view unloadable by the app.  No console output indicating the error.  When I change the  to a `<listtext...>` then it is fine (but not editable).

What I need to be able to do is to add a multiline editable field to the list, and also a text item with a lookup.

```
    <list attribute="plusgaudline" collapsible="true" displayPageSize="25" id="WorkExecution.WorkDetailView_workOrder_question_list" label="Questions" resource="workOrder">
         <listItemTemplate id="WorkExecution.WorkDetailView_workOrder_plusgaudline_listItemTemplate" layout="AuditLines">
            <listtext id="WorkExecution.WorkDetailView_workOrder_plugaudlinedescription" layoutInsertAt="item1" resourceAttribute="questionDescription" showreqattribute="mandatory"/>
            <listtext id="answer" layoutInsertAt="item4" value="Answer"/> 
            <text border="false" cssClass="copyPlanActual" editable="true" id="WorkExecution_WorkDetailView_qLD" layoutInsertAt="item3" resourceAttribute="questionLongDescription"/>
            <listtext id="WorkExecution.WorkDetailView_workOrder_vHSEStatus" layoutInsertAt="item2" resourceAttribute="vHSEStatus"/>
        </listItemTemplate>
    </list>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the layout "AuditLines" to make sure the one you're using really has a layout id defined as "item3".  Check the workOrder resource and make sure the resourceAttribute really is called "questionLongDescription". Those are usually the two places where this can go wrong.  We have tried to improve these two specific error handling cases in our next drop.

The fact that it works as listtext though sounds like maybe something stranger is going on.  We might need a PMR to track this issue.